# Zend Paginatinator trigger an error when I call $paginator->getItem()

Tags: php, zend-framework2, resultset, zend-paginator

I got an error in **Zend\Paginator\Paginator** when I call method **getItem()**

```
$select             = $myMapper->getSqlSelect();
$resultSet          = new ResultSet();
$paginatorAdapter   = new DbSelect($select, $myMapper->getAdapter(), $resultSet);
$paginator          = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);

//echo get_class($paginator); Zend\Paginator\Paginator
$paginator->getItem(1, 1);
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet as array

Everything else works fine when I don't use this method (in view, controllers, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue in ZF2. It's solved.

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6812

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies you cannot use a ResultSet Object as an array. You'll have to use methods of the ResultSet class which you can find [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Db.ResultSet.ResultSet.html).